# How to send HTML form in HTML Emails with an uploaded file?

Tags: html, forms, email, file-upload, submit

I know it is possible to send a HTML Form in a HTML eMail. [Here is an example](http://css-tricks.com/html-forms-in-html-emails/)

What I would like to know is if it is possible to attach a file in this form. That means the receiver of this mail will fill the different fields and upload a file from his computer. Then he submits the form.

The filled informations and the uploaded file will be not sent per email, but directly to an IT System. Then an appropriate script will store them.

Is it possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot have forms in HTML emails.

Most mail clients will strip the FORM tag and the fields. Consider that many web mail clients use forms for their own purposes and one embedded in an email would break the email client.

You're best to link to a web-based form.

Now you can use delimiters in emails, and parse them automatically, but this is fragile since the user can easily edit-out your delimiters.

For example, users would fill-in what's after the colon, and your code would parse the values.

> name:
>
> email: